# How implement Health checks according to response time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, health-monitoring, .net-core-3.1

I have two APIs in .net core 3.1.
I want to implement a simple health check about the response time.
But the problem is that the first API does a simple transaction and fetch results in a few milliseconds, the second one because fetch results from another API, implement business logic, store in the database, and then fetch the results, this response is about a second.

As a result, I want to implement a custom health check about the second API that if the response time is greater than 5 seconds the API is unhealthy otherwise is healthy.

I read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1
I think is something like that

```
public class ExampleHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
    public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
        HealthCheckContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var responseTime= await GetResponseTimeAsync();

        if (responseTime < 5)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                HealthCheckResult.Healthy("A healthy result."));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(
            HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("An unhealthy result."));
    }
}
```

now I have two questions

1) Is it the right way to implement something like this or there is a different way that I don't know it?

2)What is the best way to implement the response time? A filter, a middleware something else?

Comment: I never tried to implement `IHealthCheck`, I would like to delegate the health check (calls a specific API) to an external service, but you could consider StopWatch

Comment: If your upstream system is using a slow downstream system then the preferred approach would be use a [Circuit Breaker](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker) with [Timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) and use the state of the Circuit Breaker inside the Health endpoint. If it is in a **Closed** state then it is healthy otherwise it is not.

Comment: Your code won't compile without the `async` keyword. If you make it async, you probably won't need to use `FromResult` any more. You should be passing the cancellation token into `GetResponseTimeAsync` if possible.